# java programming trouble with methods

Tags: java

In Java, I just recently went over methods and I wanted to do something to put what I learned into practice. however, I just got stuck.

What I am trying to do here is have a print line of "What color is chocolate? 1. White 2. Black. 3. Brown. The answer is "

essentially my goal is to have the print line say "The answer is Brown."

Can I get a few words of advice?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //What color is chocolate? 1. White 2. Black 3. Brown

    int corAns = methodChocolate(3);
    if (corAns == 3) {
        System.out.println("Brown");
    }

    System.out.println("What color is chocolate? 1. White 2. Black 3. Brown.
                       The answer is "+corAns);
}

static int methodChocolate(int ans) {
    if (ans == 3) {
        return 3;
    } else if (ans == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else if (ans == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the numbers and color names in an associative structure like a `HashMap`, then use that to get the color names from the option number. If you don't know how to use `Map`s, you should learn them. They're pretty much essential to programming. If you're just learning methods now, it may be a little advanced for you, but it would be the best way to achieve this. You could also store the color names in a list, and use the numbers as indices into the list.

Comment: Is it doing what you want it to?  Or is this just a general call for "how does this look?"

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks ill look into it.

Comment: @MrB its not doing what i intended it to do. i am having trouble getting corAns to display "brown"

Comment: You're calling static methods wrong.  There's no need for it to be a static method at all, but if you want it to be then you need to call `Classname.staticMethodName(arguments)`

Comment: For your methodChocolate, look into using switch statements and using more than 1 return statement in your code is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Change `methodChocolate` to return a `String` like

```
static String methodChocolate(int ans) {
    if (ans == 3) {
        return "Brown";
    ...
```

and you call it like this

```
String corAns = methodChocolate(3);
```

then you should be able to print it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class example{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //input keyboard
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    //What color is chocolate? 1. White 2. Black 3. Brown
    System.out.println("What color is chocolate? \n1. White \n2. Black \n3. Brown.");
    String corAns = methodChocolate(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println("The answer is "+corAns);
}

static String methodChocolate(int n){
    switch(n){
        case 1:
            return "White";
        case 2:
            return "Black";
        case 3:
            return "Brown";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

}